# Can't get the table's description with SOQL or Rest Api

Tags: soql, rest-api, query

I'm trying to get the descriptions of the tables with SOQL query or Rest Api without succes till now.

Any idea about how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the Description field for the object, that you see in Setup when you create or edit an object?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the [Describe API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm)? Please [edit] to clarify what you're aiming for.